# TypeError: Argument to dispatchEvent must be an Event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Jest test suites are failing with enzyme v3.0 for below excerpt.

```
Object.defineProperty(document, 'createEvent', {
  value: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    initEvent: jest.fn(),
  }),
});
```

It says

> TypeError: Argument to dispatchEvent must be an Event

Comment: Did you have tests working in Enzyme 2 or are you just now starting off with Enzyme 3? What are you trying to accomplish with that code? It seems somewhat contrived.

Comment: It was working with enzyme 2. We have a resize event and trying to mock that behavior with Jest mocks.

It is straight away failing at the above code after upgrading to enzyme 3 and jest 21

Comment: Have you installed the appropriate enzyme adapter?

Comment: Yes I did. Other test suites are working as expected but not this one.